# missing positional arg in a method

Tags: tkinter

in my class circledrawer I have the method createcircle. the canvas itself runs fine but i get an error saying that I am missing a positional argument for it despite the fact that i have provided it in its definition

````
from tkinter import *
class circledrawer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.mycanvas = Canvas(self.root)
        self.root.geometry('400x400')
        self.root.resizable(width=FALSE, height= FALSE)
        self.n = 0
        self.numberlabel = Label(self.mycanvas, text= f'number of balls: {self.n}')
        self.root.bind('<Motion>',self.motion)
        self.root.bind('<Button-1>', self.createcircle)
        self.mycanvas.pack()
        self.numberlabel.pack(side='top')
        self.root.mainloop()
    
    def motion(self,event):
        self.x,self.y =event.x,event.y


    def createcircle(self, x,y):
        x = self.x
        y = self.y
        x0 = x - 5
        x1 = x + 5
        y0 = y - 5
        y1 = y + 5
        self.n += 1
        return self.mycanvas.create_oval(x0,y0,x1,y1)


circledrawer()
```

```
````

i have tried using both the @staticmethod and @classmethod as well as adding self.x and self.y in init but nothing has worked.
i expected the program to draw a circle at the current mouse position and increase the self.n counter by 1

Comment: Both function should be inside class not outside.. Can u pleas fix format code?

Answer (score 0):

use the code below:

```
from tkinter import *
class circledrawer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        
        self.root.geometry('400x400')
        self.root.resizable(width=FALSE, height= FALSE)
        
        self.mycanvas = Canvas(self.root,bg="white",height=250,width=300)
        self.mycanvas.pack()
       
        self.n = 0
        
        self.numberlabel = Label(self.root,text="number of balls: 0")
        self.numberlabel.pack(side='top')
        
        self.root.bind('<Motion>',self.motion)
        self.root.bind('<Button-1>', self.createcircle)
        
        
        self.root.mainloop()
    
    def motion(self,event):
        self.x,self.y =event.x,event.y


    def createcircle(self,event):
        x = self.x
        y = self.y
        print(x,y)
        x0 = x - 5
        x1 = x + 5
        y0 = y - 5
        y1 = y + 5
        self.n += 1
        self.mycanvas.create_oval(x0,y0,x1,y1,fill="blue")
        self.numberlabel.configure(text= f'number of balls: {self.n}')
        


circledrawer()
```

have fun :)

Comment: Not on Label. But draw on Canvas

Comment: This answer would be better if you described what you changed and why. Otherwise we have to compare the code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character.